# Is there a better way of writing the NOT IN (subquery) thing in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there a better way of writing this kind of thing?

```
SELECT * from table_a WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_b)
```

It's shown [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/31/derived-tables-and-views-performance/) that views are faster than subqueries, but it's not like you can do `SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id NOT IN view_b`, so I'm curious if there's a better way or if that's just what we have to live with.

Comment: You can do SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id NOT IN view_b if view_b returns the id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* from table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON (a.id = b.id)
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

You can also use `NOT EXISTS` (I believe it might have a bit worse performance in mysql though) :

```
SELECT a.* from table_a a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_b b WHERE b.id = a.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Derived tables:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table_b
        ) b
JOIN    table_a a
ON      a.id = b.id
```

have nothing to do with `IN` predicates:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_a
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    table_b
        )
```

The subquery in the `IN` predicate is never materialized.

This way is actually the most efficient if you have an index on `table_b.id`.

Here are two more:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_a a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL 
        FROM    table_b b
        WHERE   b.id = a.id
        )
```

and

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_a a
LEFT JOIN
        table_b b
ON      b.id = a.id
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
```

This query may also be efficient if `table_b.id` cannot be indexed (say, it's a derived expression) and `table_a.id` is `UNIQUE`:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, 1 AS s
        FROM    table_a
        UNION
        SELECT  id, -1 AS s
        FROM    table_b
        ) q
JOIN    table_a a
ON      a.id = q.id
GROUP BY
        a.id
HAVING  MAX(s) = 1
```

You may want to read this article:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: More efficient than a `JOIN`?

Comment: Another sql lesson. Great post. :)